# Invoking a trigger from another trigger - execution context

Tags: apex, trigger, dml

For Example there's a trigger on Account (after update ) in it I update the address of 10000 contacts(max for all accounts combined) , now I have an trigger(after update) on contact for each contact i update campaign record . Will the Account and contact trigger be running in different context or apex transactions ? and if they run in same context will it generate an error due to some DML limit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If trigger starts working from another trigger, they are executed in same transaction.

It can be easily tested by these samples:

**1st Account trigger that calls Opportunity trigger:**

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after insert) {
    //in 1st trigger you see opps update, so they call 2nd trigger
    system.debug('1st trigger: before SOQL: ' + Limits.getQueries());
    List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity];
    system.debug('1st trigger: after SOQL: ' + Limits.getQueries());
    update opps;
}
```

**2nd Opportunity trigger:**

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before update) {
    system.debug('2nd trigger: before SOQL: ' + Limits.getQueries());
    List<Organization> org = [SELECT Id FROM Organization];
    system.debug('2nd trigger: after SOQL: ' + Limits.getQueries());
}
```

**Debug logs:**

[image]

So as you can see, they both share limits in one transaction.